# Django 1.5 Custom User Model not validating in templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-1.5

I have info in the django documentation to create my custom user profile, something [pretty similar](https://gist.github.com/xpostudio4/7680855) to what they show [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/), the problem is that when I am trying to access information about if the user is logged in like the following:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}           
    <li ><a href="/profiles/signout">Signout</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li ><a href="/profiles/signin/">Acceder</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/profiles/signup/">Registrate</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

how I am supposed to access the information if the user is logged in with the new customised user.

Comment: instead of `request.user`, just use `user.is_authenticated`

Comment: Saved my life, can you please create this as an answer to give you the points. Also would be awesome if you can explain with more details the difference from 1.4 and 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `request.user.is_authenticated` to just `user.is_authenticated`

When you include the middleware `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in the settings, the `user` object would be available in the template.

[Read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth)

Comment: I am trying to find an appropriate link which covers this.